# How to make an image fill the entire slide in an rmarkdown presentation using ioslides?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I want to have an image to fill the whole slide.
I have tried to use a div with absolute positioning, however, that will position the image partly outside of the slide.

I think I could make that work, if I hard code the resolution in, however, I would like to make it work on another machine as well. (and preferably even with the wide screen switching)

An example to reproduce/test:

```
---
title: "some title"
author: Me
company: Me
date: 21-02-2017
output:
    ioslides_presentation

---

##

![test image](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yaqe1qesQ8c/maxresdefault.jpg)
```

edit:
I am aware of:
[Rpresentation in Rstudio - Make image fill out the whole screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619319/rpresentation-in-rstudio-make-image-fill-out-the-whole-screen)
However, there they switched to slidy_presentation and I already have custom css for ioslides. If possible I would like to stay with ioslides. And it should be possible, right? :)

Comment: Have you read this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619319/rpresentation-in-rstudio-make-image-fill-out-the-whole-screen

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that, but in that post he switched away from ioslides. I would prefer not to do that, since I already have custom css for ioslides.

Answer (score 5):

I got an idea when I was looking for getting my text output even smaller.

I found this: [Markdown: Change default font size of code chunks in ioslides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564352/markdown-change-default-font-size-of-code-chunks-in-ioslides)

Now I am using the following custom css:

```
.fullslide img {
  margin-top: -85px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
```

Then in in the rmarkdown file I can do:

```
## {.fullslide}

![](image.jpg)
```

If you now want to make sure that you get the full image, make sure the image has the following dimensions:

- widescreen: 1100 x 700
- normal: 900 x 700

I just make sure I edit them using GIMP or something.
I have not yet figured out how I can suppress the page numbering, but apparently you cannot suppress page numbers on a per slide basis. :(